# What is the return type of a "count" query against MySQL using Java JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, count

```java
String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table1";
ResultSet rs = DBConnection.executeQuery(query);
```

The above code works fine; however:

```java
long count = rs.getLong("count");
```

This wont work, it throws SQLException.  How should I get data from the `ResultSet`?

Comment: can you do Long.valueOf(rs.getString("count")) ? but that's strange, this should work. Are you sure you have invoked rs.next() before long tmpLong = rs.getLong("count"); ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
long tmpLong = rs.getLong(1);
```

should work from what I can recall.

EDIT:

of course:

```
rs.next();
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you called `rs.next()` before calling `rs.getLong("count");`

Answer (score 0):

`rs.getLong` has 2 versions `rs.getLong(java.lang.String)` and `rs.getLong(int)`. For the string version use:

```
long count = rs.getLong("COUNT(*)");
```

Since the column name is `COUNT(*)`

Based on the query used:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table1
```